# Missing mod_access_compat.so - how to compile

Tags: apache-2.4

I upgraded to Apache 2.4 from 2.2 and noticed that I am missing the `mod_access_compat.so` file in the modules directory. My question is simple, how do I compile this file?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to have been [deprecated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) and replaced by [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html). Though there are [RPMs](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=apache-mod_access_compat) (I see no DEB packages) that claim to be compatible with appache 2.4.

Comment: To add onto what [ClassicThunder](http://serverfault.com/users/116788/classicthunder) wrote, the following documentation from [the Apache Project](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) should give you some insight especially this part: > The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Comment: [root@ADM-MAP-TEST-APP-ENGG conf]# rpm -ivh apache-mod_access_compat-2.4.2-0.1-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm
warning: apache-mod_access_compat-2.4.2-0.1-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 26752624
error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by apache-mod_access_compat-2.4.2-0.1.x86_64

Comment: I want to migrate virtual host site from one ec2-instance to another but getting mod_access_compat.so error, My apache version is same on both boxes [root@ADM-MAP-TEST-APP-ENGG conf]# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix)

Comment: Server built:   Jul 14 2008 15:27:43
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:15
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.11, APR-Util 1.2.10
Compiled using: APR 1.2.11, APR-Util 1.2.10
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no

Comment: forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP

Comment: -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT

Comment: -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"

Comment: -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"